# Matlab cannot find function

Tags: matlab, command, command-prompt

I have a really simple problem with matlab, but I cannot seem to find my error.
I have a file mfile.m, which contains the lines:

```
x=32
disp(x)
```

I open matlab and run the file using f9, output shows 32 two times, which is correct.

I now try to run the exact same file form the command prompt (Win7):

`matlab -nosplash -r mfile.m`

Output: Undefined variable "mfile" or function "mfile.m".
Matlab cannot find the file even though the command prompt and current workdir is the same as mfile.m is stored in. This has been bugging me for quite some time now, any suggestions on why I fail to launch from cmd?

Comment: Try this - `matlab -nosplash -r 'mfile'`

Comment: It returned:
ans =
mfile

Comment: Found it, seems that I should exclude '.m'. Just typing matlab -nosplash -r mfile worked just fine.

Comment: Consider answering your own question (and in time accepting that answer) to help others in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the -r option takes just the filename without an extension.
Changing `matlab -nosplash -r mfile.m` into `matlab -nosplash -r mfile` made the trick.